# Viewing Stored Procedures in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio as described in the MSDN documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx

but when I try to add a SP as query to a table adapter in the DataSet Designer, via the TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard and selecting the Use Existing Stored Procedure, I don't have any stored procedures which I am able to select from, nothing turns up.

How do I get these to display? Is it a permission-ing issue? What permissions does the login need to have to access the stored procedures?

Thanks for the help,

Comment: are you pointing at the right database?

Comment: yep, same database from which the dataset is created from using the wizard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your permissions on the database, mayhaps you have the right to create the sp, but not necessarily to see or execute it.

edit: jsut re-read you post.  make sure you have the execute permission on the database/schema.

edit 2: also, make sure that the login you're using is actually assigned to the database you're wanting to use.